# Python Google App Engine Cron Job/Scheduled task Not Working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, python-2.7

I am creating this cron job to get twitter feeds and store it in datastore. I tried everything, but my cronjob is not working. I read following articles/tutorials and some stackoverflow questions, but I can't solve this out.

> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron
>
> http://cloudartisan.com/posts/2010-06-02-scheduled-tasks-with-google-app-engine-python/

Here is my code

This is cron.ymal

```
cron:
- description : capture twitter feed 
  url : /twittertask
  schedule: every 1 minutes
  target: version-2
```

This is the class I need to do the job.

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Twitt(db.Model):
    created_at = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    id = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    text = db.StringProperty(required = True)

class TwitterTask(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=BeijingAir&count=10"

        json_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

        data = json.loads(json_string)

        for item in data:
            created_at_item = item['created_at']
            text_item = item['text']
            id_item = item['id']

            e = Twitt(id = created_at_item, text = text_item, id = id_item)
            e.put()

        self.response.out.write('Hello prueba!')
```

This is app.ymal

```
application: cronjob
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.app

- url: /twittertask
  script: twittertask.app
```

This is index.py

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.write('Hello, Check Admin')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)

def main():

    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Well, I can't find where is the error. I tested on my dev server. I didn't upload it to google app engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron does not work on the local dev sever. Upload it to the cloud and it'll work.

Visit your appserver locally:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/admin
```

and click on "Cron jobs".

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/admin/cron
```

And it will say "In production, this would run at these times:"

your schedule here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I uploaded it to google app engine. Now I get an error called 2012/09/06 10:28:15 on time Failed

Comment: Let it run to the next cycle. I've had that on occasion and then it's worked fine the next time. Never got round to working it out but no doubt there will be something in the logs.

Comment: Also a quick solution to get timed refreshes working locally is to use Opera browser and set it to refresh the page in question every N minutes/seconds.

Comment: Well, it supposed to run every minute. And I waited more than 5 minutes. Can you check whether there is no errors in my cron.ymal or app.ymal file. The processing class (TwitterTask) is correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: check the line: url : /twittertask as If you have a space there inbetween "url" and ":" it probably won't work. And description also has a space inbetween the colon and the value. Checking my cron.yaml I have no spaces.

Comment: Well, Thanks! The problem was task must return 200 OK HTTP Response. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your app.yaml. URLs are matched from top to bottom, but your first handler matches *all* URLs. Move the `twittertask` entry so it's first under `handlers`.

Comment: But even after I change that in dev server, I get 404 Error message.